# Unit Testing php from command line throws error at com_create_guid()

Tags: php, windows, unit-testing, command, phpunit

I am writing unit tests using PHPUnit 4.8 with Laravel 5.1, OS is Windows 10.

One of these tests involves adding a new record to a database using an array of attributes. I am not changing any of the existing code, it is not my material. Within that array, the following appears.:

`$attributes[]`

```
'TAX_EXEMPT_NO'      => $customer->TAX_EXEMPT_NO,
'DOC_GUID'           => com_create_guid(),
'BILL_TO_CONTACT_ID' => 1,
```

where [`com_create_guid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) is a PHP global function for generating a global unique identifier.

Then my test file:

`# OrderTest.php`

```
class ApiCpOrderTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testPutDocumentWithNewDocNoContacts()    
    {
            $doc = $this->getOrder();

            $doc->TKT_NO = null;
            $doc->DRW_ID = 1;
            $doc = $doc->toArray();
            $this->doc['CONTACTS'] = null;

            $this->assertInternalType('object', $this->orderObj->putDocument($this->docTypT, $doc));
        }
}
```

Running it from the command line, 
`phpunit tests/path/OrderTest.php` throws this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  **Call to undefined function
>   App\Lib\Api\CounterPoint\com_create_guid()** in
>   C:\Users\cmahoney\workspace\csos-counterpoint-org-trunk\app\Lib\Api\CounterPoint\Order.php
>   on line 132

**I am not rewriting any of the existing code- that needs to be untouched.** Is there any way that I can get the command line to understand `com_create_guid` or other php functions while running tests? Again, the issue is when the console begins executing scripts in another file (which I can not edit) and does not undrstand com_create_guid().

Comment: Maybe use it like this in the array `'DOC_GUID' => \com_create_guid(),`, or is this function under that namespace?

Comment: That involves editing the original file, which I am not doing.